# How to use a cut in a sed statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, cut

I have this sed statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f ! -name 'checkData' ! -name 'correctData' ! -name 'makeStructure' -exec sed -i "1{s|.*|{}|;s|.*/testarea/||;s|/[^/]*$||;s/[/]/-/g;}" {} \;
```

Currently it's doing exactly what I need it to, but instead of bringing up the date in the format that I want of:

> 2000-01-18

It's returning the date as

> .-2000-01-18

I've been trying to work out which part I need to change to get rid of the .- but I'm not having much luck.
Is there a way to just cut the first 2 characters out of the result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the original string look like?

Comment: Basically this is being used to change the first line of every file within a parent directory named "testarea" in this example from a date which could or could not have null values, into the directory, so for example, this file is in testarea/2000/01/18 so its changed the date in the file to 2000-01-18 although its showing with ./ at the start whereas i just want it to change it all to the date

Comment: Having the original string will be extremely helpful. In any case, if all of your outputs start with ".-", why don't you just kill it with an extra command in your sed script? Just add something like `s/^\.-//`

Comment: Or, if you want to cut just 2 characters at the beginning, any two characters, then it would be `s/^..//`

Comment: That first piece of code does exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: In your question you say the string has `.-` although in your comments you've indicated `./`... which is it?

Comment: Technically its ./ since it takes the directories but then i added s/[/]/-/g; in the code to change it to .-

Comment: Did you try using the `basename` command as shown below?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to employ `basename` into your `find` command:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'checkData' ! -name 'correctData' ! -name 'makeStructure' \
-exec basename {} \; | \
sed -i "1{s|.*|{}|;s|.*/testarea/||;s|/[^/]*$||;s/[/]/-/g;}"
```

This should remove the `./` at the beggining of your filenames.